# re-sysprep'ing the master image of a windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

If I have sysprep'ed a windows 7 master computer (i.e. a computer on which the original image is built), and then realise that I missed something out.

How do I add what I missed out and re-sysprep it?

I understanded that sysprep'ing a cloned computer is not supported by Microsoft.  Does that mean re-sysprep'ing the original computer is also not supported by Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

it depends what you missed out. if it would be just files or registary enteries or even some microsoft update you can use the windows AIK to mount the WIM file image of the computer then you can make changes to the image then commit the changes to the image then use that image.

to mount and modify a wim image can be found here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824814.aspx

making changes to the registary you need to open regedit click on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" or "HKEY_USERS" then click file then "Load Hive" then you just need to navigate to the file location on the image,

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER" -> MOUNTDIR\Users\"username or Default"\NTUser.dat
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM" -> MOUNTDIR\Windows\system32\config\Sam
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security" -> MOUNTDIR\Windows\system32\config\Security
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software" -> MOUNTDIR\Windows\system32\config\Software
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System" -> MOUNTDIR\Windows\system32\config\System

or finaly to add updates to a windows 7/8 image you can use the following guide form microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794819%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

hope this helps

Craig

Answer (score 1):

In addition to vip32’s suggestions for offline editing of an image:

The Resetting Windows Activation section of the TechNet article ‘[How Sysprep Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744512(v=ws.10).aspx)’ explains that while sysprep can be run any number of times, the clock for Windows Product Activation can only be reset three times. If you have reached the limit, then you will have to rebuild your master from scratch. If you have not reached the limit, you can re-run sysprep and re-capture the image for deployment. 
When you run sysprep with the /Generalize switch, which is required before capturing the final image, the activation clock is reset.

To clarify the [unsupported sysprep scenarios](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828287), you cannot clone a non-sysprepped image to another machine, and then run sysprep as the final step in the deployment. The image you deploy must be sysprepped prior to deployment. You can, however, deploy your sysprepped image, make changes, run sysprep again, and then re-capture the image for deployment. However, as mentioned above, you will eventually run into the activation limit if you do this too many times. You can work around this limit by setting up your master on a virtual machine and capturing a snapshot of the image just before you run sysprep. If you need to make any changes after this, simply re-load the snapshot, make your changes, re-capture a new snapshot and then run sysprep, and capture the new image for deployment.

Hope this helps,